# Playing audio after x conditions have met (Python-Pygame)

Tags: python, audio

I wanted to know how I could correct this:

```
    if xFarmer == xFarmer +4 == True
            and:
                    xGoat == xGoat +4 == True
                    and:
                            xWolf == xWolf +4 == True
                            and:
                                    xCabbage == xCabbage +4 == True:
                                            mixer.init()
                                            mixer.music.set_volume(1.0)
                                            mixer.music.load('champion.wav')
                                            mixer.music.play()
```

Basically so if all those conditions are true, only then the sound plays?

Explanation too, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I came across this question in a review queue, and just wanted to let you know -- saying "Explanation too, thanks!" is a pretty abrupt way to ask someone to do work for you. You'll have much better luck with future questions if you show you've made a sincere effort to find a solution yourself -- see http://whathaveyoutried.com for a good essay on this. Good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

Im not sure what you are trying to do

however `if x == y:`  is exactly the same as `if x == y == True:` and it is much more readable

also there is never an instance where `x == x+4`  `x` will equal `x` not `x+4`.

```
if xFarmer == "something" and xGoat == "something" and xWolf == "something" and xCabbage == "something":
    play_music()
```

it seems as though you are very confused about basic python structures and if/else logic in general.  I would go work through some beginner tutorials (dont just copy and paste, actually follow along and learn the concepts)